# How to Load jQuery Template

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I keep getting same error every time i try to load my jQuery template. 
On document ready i get list of Items as a json list, and on succes this code run:

```
 function add(result) {
            var panel = $('#MainContent_Panel1');
            for (var k = 0; k < result.d.length; k++) {
                $("#template").tmpl(result.d[k]).appendTo("#MainContent_Panel1");

            }

        }
```

Here is my Template :

```
   <script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ >

        <div id ="myID" style="background-color: red">
        <span questionLabelGroup="$i">Question : ${Uid}</span>
        <span questionTextGroup="$i">Hello ${Content}<br /></span>
        <span answerLabelGroup="$i">Answer : </span>
        <input  type='text' questionID="$guid"/>
        <input type='button' Class='addAnswerButton' addQuestionButtonGroup='"$i"' value='Add Question' />
        <hr />
        </div>

        </script>
```

and i keep getting this error: TypeError: $("#template").tmpl is not a function. Any ideas what i did wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are including the jQuery $.tmpl() file?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the jquery template plugin might not be loaded. have you included the script tag loading the plug-in? if so, is it being loaded before the snippet of code in your example is being executed?